# Access SharePoint 2013 data from remote apps using the cross-domain library?

Tags: 2013, office-365

I am follow [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx) article for SharePoint 2013 data from remote apps using cross-domain library.

i have selected App-Project as `Autohosted` and follow same steps with carefully.

my App is successfully installed on My SharePoint 2013. but when going to open that app output is :

> The host web title is: Could not complete cross-domain call: App Web is not deployed for this app's request url http://contoso.com

please see screenshot :

[image]

I am using Cloud Share account : `SharePoint Server 2013 RTM`

Any Idea??

Comment: How do you proceed to access the App when it's deployed? From your SharePoint environment? When deployed, it should create it's App Web automatically (Figure 1 in the link above has the entry in the left hand navigation 'SharePointApp1', that's the App Web).

Comment: i have take app project as 'autohost' and hit `F5` for deployed. one more things is that i have keep Start up Project is 'SharePoint Project' and after executed `F5` I can able to see the my app and give it to Trust App. after this its automatically redirect above Images URL. Got Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check this msdn post How we get  list items by using the cross-domain library (CSOM)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Get-items-d48150ae#content